# Expand immidiate next even rows onclicking odd rows using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I want to create table like in this site:

```
https://www.avast.com/en-in/exploit-protection.php
```

I tried with below code but something is happening wrong , I am beginner of jquery.Reading data from mysql php to show.

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#myTable tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#myTable tr:first-child").show();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tr").click(function(){
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id ='myTable' class='tablesorter' style='table-layout:fixed;'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class='header' width='4%'>Wild</th>
                                    <th class='header ' width='12%'>Release Date</th>
                                    <th class='header' width='12%'>Exploit Name1</th>
                                    <th data-sorter='false' width='18%'>Name2</th>
                                    <th data-sorter='false' width='53%'>Comments</th>
                                    <th data-sorter='false' width='1%'></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>        <i hidden>1</i><img src='ex.png' alt='' border=3 height=25 width=25></img>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>03/11/2015</td>
                                    <td><b> CVE-2015-1623</b></td>
                                    <td  style='word-wrap:break-word;'>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>ABC</li>
                                            <li>XYZ</li>
                                            <li>PQR</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style='word-wrap:break-word;'>
                                        Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code or cause ...       
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class='arrow'></div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <b>Link: </b>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href =http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-1623 target ='_blank'>http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2015-1623<br></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
```

Please let me know what is wrong in jquery.

Comment: What is it doing wrong when you try to use it?

Comment: rows getting hidden on clicking the odd rows, It is not expanding the immediate next row

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML, instead of the PHP script, so we can try it?

Comment: Your code seems to work. I click on the first row, it toggles the second row.